# HttpURLConnection getInputStream is too slow

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I have a site with an API which I use to get JSON data. I have a `ConnectClass` class, an instance of which is created each time a request is sent. When an instance of `ConnectClass` is created, a new `HttpURLConnection` object is created, `.setup()`ed and `.connect()`ed:

```
class ConnectClass  {
        private HttpURLConnection connection;

        private String link;
        private REQUEST_TYPE requestType;
        private URL url;
        private AccessToken accessToken;  

        public String send() throws Exception  {
                connection.connect();
                System.out.println("start get input stream");  //from this
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

                System.out.println("end get input stream");  //to this takes too long

                System.out.println("Start scanner");
                String inputString = new Scanner(input, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
                System.out.println("End scanner");
                input.close();

                return inputString;  //returns response JSON string
        }

        public ConnectClass(String link, AccessToken accessToken, REQUEST_TYPE requestType)  throws Exception {
            this.link = link;
            this.accessToken = accessToken;
            this.requestType = requestType;

            this.url = new URL(link);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)  url.openConnection();
            setup();
        }

        private void setup() throws Exception {
            //connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(100);  //doesn't really change things 
            //connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
            connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "some description v2.0");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken.ACCESS_TOKEN_LONG);
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        }
    }
```

However, I need to send 10 requests like this in a loop. And each request takes about 1.3 seconds, when all 10 requests should take no more than 1-2 seconds combined. I've found most time is spend on getting input stream and processing it: `InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();` - it takes about 0.6-1 second and `String inputString = new Scanner(input, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\Z").next();` takes about 0.1-0.2 seconds.

Is there anything I can do to lower the time per request?

I tried setting connect timeout to as low as 100, but it didn't have a visible effect.

**EDIT**: Response JSON is rather big. `connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");` and then using `InputStream input = new GZIPInputStream(connection.getInputStream());` helps, but it only saves about 4-5 seconds in total.

I can't use concurrent requests - every new request depends on the previous one (takes a parameter from previous input JSON and passes it in a new request, in a link).

Comment: When you say  "should take no more than 1-2 seconds combined" is it that you want it to take 1-2 seconds or is it that you verified with some other tool, cURL for example, that 10 requests as you construct them in `setup()` take 1-2 seconds?

Comment: @David Soroko I want it to take 1-2 seconds and other people who used that site's API said it takes that long for them - though most of them use Python. I also tested the request in Postman and it takes 4-6 seconds to make 10 requests.

Comment: This means that the *server* is slow. `getInputStream()` in this code sends the request and waits for the response headers. NB 1. Calling. `setDoOutput(true)` with a request method of GET makes no sense whatsoever. 2. You don't need to call `connect()` explicitly: it happens automatically anyway. 3. it makes no sense to save the `HttpURLConnection` object in the class. You can only use it once.

Comment: @user207421 Well I get a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Chunked encoding streaming mode set java.net.ProtocolException: cannot write to a URLConnection if doOutput=false - call setDoOutput(true)` error when I remove `connection.setDoOutput(true);`, so it looks like it's necessary. As for storing `HttpURLConnection`, it's my custom wrapper which I find easier to use, since it makes it possible for me to get a response JSON with a one line `String response = new ConnectClass(...).send()`.

Comment: So this isn't the real code. You are writing to the connection output stream. This means that you have *another* problem: you are sending a body with a GET request. This is not legal HTTP. Almost certainly your server is expecting a POST, which is the default when you call `setDoOutput(true)`. So leave that and delete the `setRequestMethod()` call.

Comment: I had `connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);` which caused the error. However when I remove the chunked bit and remove the `setDoOutput`, I still get the error: `java.net.ProtocolException: cannot write to a URLConnection if doOutput=false - call setDoOutput(true)` and `java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL` which isn't present when `setDoOutput` is true

Comment: No chunked streaming mode in your question. So, again, this isn't the real code. You are getting all this from what line of code? Please clarify your question, and post the real code. Chunked streaming mode only affects the output of the request, and if you aren't doing any output you don't need it, or `setDoOutput(true)` either, and if you do need `setDoOutput(true)` you can't possibly also need to set the request method back to GET. Lots of confusion here, and no real code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performance issue with HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23343248/performance-issue-with-httpurlconnection)

Comment: Nothing has changed here. Your code still doesn't make sense, and you still haven't answered my question. And here's another one: is your server expecting a GET or a POST?

Comment: @user207421 The code I posted is the same I myself run. The server expects GET or at least so its API docs state.

Comment: So why all the output stuff? and from what line of code do you get your claimed `ProtocolException` when you remove it? I asked you that two hours ago?

Comment: @user207421 OK, you were right - the error was because a POST request for access_token that was sent earlier used the same class. Now I've removed `setDoOutput(true)` from `GET` requests and it works fine. However, it is still slow, so the original question still stands.

Comment: And so does my original comment. It is the server that is slow. This Java code does hardly anything except I/O.

Comment: Is the URL HTTPS? It might be worth watching the connections with Wireshark or TCP dump to see if anything jumps out, e.g. no connection reuse and every connection is renegotating SSL slowly / with more round trips than you'd expect. Or if the main delay is after you've posted the request i.e. it is the server and there's nothing you can do about it except complain to the service provider.

Comment: @user207421 Perhaps, there are better compression/decompression options or better libraries for Java.

Answer (score 1):

Bellow is your code with bits removed to allow compilation. `Main` doing a `GET` on Google. On my machine `send` takes ~ 300 millis. to complete. If you are getting a similar timing, I would suggest that you check that your account has been set up properly and is not throttled for example

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

class ConnectClass {
    private HttpURLConnection connection;

    private String link;
    private URL url;

    public String send() throws Exception {
        connection.connect();
        System.out.println("start get input stream");  //from this
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

        System.out.println("end get input stream");  //to this takes too long

        System.out.println("Start scanner");
        String inputString = new Scanner(input, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
        System.out.println("End scanner");
        input.close();


//        System.out.println(inputString);
        return inputString;  //returns response JSON string
    }

    public ConnectClass(String link) throws Exception {
        this.link = link;

        this.url = new URL(link);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        setup();
    }

    private void setup() throws Exception {
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(100);  //doesn't really change things
        connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "some description v2.0");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ConnectClass cc = new  ConnectClass("https://www.google.com");

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        cc.send();
        System.out.println("Done in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
    }
}
```

Another possibility is that you are receiving a large response. If so you may want to use an HTTP client that supports compression.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about compression. I didn't know it's a thing. Response JSON is indeed pretty big, I added `connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");` to `setup()` method and now it takes about 8-9 seconds, which is better than the previous result (13-14 seconds).